# pip wxpython gives ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'attrdict'

Tags: python, pip, wxpython

Installing wxpython with pip gives the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'attrdict'`

### Details:

py -3.10-64 -m pip install -U wxpython

```
Collecting wxpython
  Using cached wxPython-4.2.0.tar.gz (71.0 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Bernard\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dokcizpt\wxpython_662eefb4314c47eba7b194b4d07a8e18\setup.py", line 27, in <module>
          from buildtools.config import Config, msg, opj, runcmd, canGetSOName, getSOName
        File "C:\Users\Bernard\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dokcizpt\wxpython_662eefb4314c47eba7b194b4d07a8e18\buildtools\config.py", line 30, in <module>
          from attrdict import AttrDict
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'attrdict'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

### What works

installing other packages works, e.g.

py -3.10-64 -m pip install -U mido
Requirement already satisfied: mido in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (1.2.10)

### Version info

Windows 10 22H2
pip 23.0.1 from C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.11)

### Context

This is used in the fluidpatcher installer, I logged a bug [here](https://github.com/albedozero/fluidpatcher/issues/74).

## Update 1

Seems to be a known issue reported here: https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/2296

Tried workaround of manually installing

```
py -3.10-64 -m pip install -U attrdict3
```

Which installs.

Then retried the wxpython install

```
py -3.10-64 -m pip install -U wxpython
```

Which fails, this time with a different error message

```
Collecting wxpython
  Using cached wxPython-4.2.0.tar.gz (71.0 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from wxpython) (9.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from wxpython) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from wxpython) (1.24.2)
Installing collected packages: wxpython
  DEPRECATION: wxpython is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for wxpython ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for wxpython did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [49 lines of output]
      C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:771: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'license-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'license_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:317: DistDeprecationWarning: use_2to3 is ignored.
        warnings.warn(f"{attr} is ignored.", DistDeprecationWarning)
      running install
      C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      Will build using: "C:\Python311\python.exe"
      3.11.0 (main, Oct 24 2022, 18:26:48) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)]
      Python's architecture is 64bit
      cfg.VERSION: 4.2.0

      Running command: build
      Running command: build_wx
      Command '"C:\Python311\python.exe" -c "import os, sys, setuptools.msvc; setuptools.msvc.isfile = lambda path: path is not None and os.path.isfile(path); ei = setuptools.msvc.EnvironmentInfo('x64', vc_min_ver=14.0); env = ei.return_env(); env['vc_ver'] = ei.vc_ver; env['vs_ver'] = ei.vs_ver; env['arch'] = ei.pi.arch; env['py_ver'] = sys.version_info[:2]; print(env)"' failed with exit code 1.
      Traceback (most recent call last):

        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

        File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1120, in __init__

          self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)

                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 596, in __init__

          vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vs_ver())

                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 610, in _find_latest_available_vs_ver

          raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(

      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: No Microsoft Visual C++ version found
      Finished command: build_wx (0m1.80s)
      Finished command: build (0m1.80s)
      WARNING: Building this way assumes that all generated files have been
      generated already.  If that is not the case then use build.py directly
      to generate the source and perform the build stage.  You can use
      --skip-build with the bdist_* or install commands to avoid this
      message and the wxWidgets and Phoenix build steps in the future.

      "C:\Python311\python.exe" -u build.py build
      Command '"C:\Python311\python.exe" -u build.py build' failed with exit code 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> wxpython
```

## Update 2

Workaround: install Python 3.10.

Comment: Found issue in issue tracker: https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/2296

Comment: So, did installing `attrdict3` solve your issue?

Comment: Only solved getting to the next error, see update 1 in question

Comment: _"... No Microsoft Visual C++ version found ..."_  I installed `wxpython` in a virtual environment on my Linux box and it spent quite a bit of time compiling.

Comment: I am still experiencing this in python 3.10.10. Also tried 3.11.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are still interested: I have successfully installed wxPython on Windows, under WinPython 3.11.1 (got it from SouceForge) with:

```
pip install -U attrdict3
pip install wxpython
```

After installation, in the `\Lib\site-packages\wx` dir, you have to rename all files with no extension manually so they have the `.pyd` extension.